# TileMill MapBox map pans to different world without any markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, mapbox, tilemill

I have a map I exported from tilemill, made a mapbox map and threw some points on it.  The view starts off looking at the US, with a marker somewhere in the middle.  If I pan left until the next time I see the US, the markers are gone.  Here's the code minus the geoJson data.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'natecraft1.xdan61or').setView([-102, 39], 4);
map.markerLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
  var marker = e.layer;
  var feature = marker.feature;
  var image = feature.properties.images
  // var img = images

  // Create custom popup content
var popupContent = '<img class="pics" src="' + image + '" />'
  marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
    closeButton: false,
    minWidth: 320,
    offset: [180, 20]
  });
});

map.markerLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);

map.markerLayer.on('click', function(e) {
  e.layer.openPopup(); 
var lat = e.layer.getLatLng().lat;
  var lng = e.layer.getLatLng().lng;

  map.panTo([lat+5, lng+5], 2);

});
  map.markerLayer.on('', function(e) {
  e.layer.closePopup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tilelayer is wrapping around the globe for coordinates [outside of the (-180, 180) range](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-continuousworld). Best option is to set the `maxBounds` option so users don't pan outside of that map and just get bounced back.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-9ijuk24y').setView([0,0], 2);
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.map-9ijuk24y', {
  noWrap: true,
  minZoom: 3
}).addTo(map);
map.options.maxBounds = map.getBounds();
```

Here's a [live demo](http://bl.ocks.org/geraldarthur/3d2b2ae2957d750412ff) of what that would look like